# Cypress : how to group tests like "Smoke", "Sanity" and "regression"

Tags: cypress

i m facing an problem to how to group my test in "Smoke", "Sanity" and "regression"? Please suggest how can we achieve this  using cypress.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this plugin https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-grep to tag tests as `smoke`, `stable`, etc. You can check out its homepage for usage and use cases. I recommend to go with this option since it's simple.

Or if you prefer, you can create your own plugin to filter tests based on the test case name since Cypress also provides hooks (borrowed from Mocha).

```
before(() => {
  // root-level hook
  // runs once before all tests
})

beforeEach(() => {
  // root-level hook
  // runs before every test block
})

afterEach(() => {
  // runs after each test block
})

after(() => {
  // runs once all tests are done
})

describe('Hooks', () => {
  before(() => {
    // runs once before all tests in the block
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    // runs before each test in the block
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    // runs after each test in the block
  })

  after(() => {
    // runs once after all tests in the block
  })
})
```

Since we want this implementation applied for all specs, the right place to put it in is /cypress/support/index.js

```
beforeEach(function() {
    // get tags passed from command
    const tags = Cypress.env('tagName').split(",");

    // exit if no tag or filter defined - we have nothing to do here
    if ( !tags ) return;

    // get current test's title (which also contains tag/s)
    const testName = Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.title

    // check if current test contains at least 1 targetted tag
    for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
        if ( testName.includes(tags[i]) ) return;
    }

    // skip current test run if test doesn't contain targetted tag/s
    this.skip();
})
```

In your spec files, you can add tag/s for your tests

```
describe('this is a test for tests selection', () => {
    it('test #1 [@smoke, @functional, @e2e]', () => {
        console.log("this is a test #1")
    })

    it('test #2[@e2e]', () => {
        console.log("this is a test #2")
    })
})
```

Lastly, in your command, you specify which tag/s to be used for filtering your tests

```
cypress_tagName="@functional, @smoke" npm run cy:open
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plugin [cypress-tags](https://github.com/annaet/cypress-tags)

To install:

```js
npm install cypress-tags
```

After Installation, go to `cypress/support/index.js` and add:

```js
// cypress/plugins/index.js
const tagify = require('cypress-tags');

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', tagify(config));
};
```

In your tests, you can add your tags to either `describe` or `it` blocks -

```js
describe(['regression'], 'This will tag every test inside the describe with the "my-feature" tag', function () { ... });

it(['smoke'], 'This is a smoke test', function () { ... });

it(['wip'], 'This is a work-in-progress test', function () { ... });
```

After writing the tags, select tests by passing a comma separated list of tags to the Cypress environment variable `CYPRESS_INCLUDE_TAGS`.

```js
CYPRESS_INCLUDE_TAGS=smoke,regression npx cypress run
```

Skip tests by passing a comma-separated list of tags to the Cypress environment variable `CYPRESS_EXCLUDE_TAGS`.

```js
CYPRESS_EXCLUDE_TAGS=wip npx cypress run
```

Combine the two for more complex testing strategies.

```js
CYPRESS_INCLUDE_TAGS=smoke,regression CYPRESS_EXCLUDE_TAGS=wip npx cypress run
```